# How to disable Fast Deployment in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making a android app and when I try to deploy it, I got the following error

Deployment failed due to an error in FastDev assembly synchronization.

I have read in the Web, that I could resolve it if I disable Fast Deployment option, for it, Could anybody say me how I could do it in VS2013 or other place?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro

Answer (score 8):

In VS2013, Right Click The Android Project -> Properties -> Build Options -> Uncheck: Use Fast Deployment

Comment: Please just edit your question rather than commenting your update!

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.1 to 15.9.35) & Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.4):

1. Right-mouse click the Project in Visual Studio
2. Select Properties
3. Go to "Android Options"
4. Uncheck: "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)"

Comment: + Same Works in VS 2022 as well.

Answer (score 2):

try it: Project / Project Options / Android Build / Fast deployment

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your fast answer. I found the fast deployment in VS2013 in Project / Propierties Options / Android Build / Fast deployment and uncheck it . Now I have a Internal error

Comment: It is the following. 
Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/XamFeed.Droid-Signed.apk

Comment: For it, Could anyboby help me with that? Thanks in advance